ERC20 Token `ERC20InsufficientAllowance` Error on `transferFrom` function
I have been trying to develop my own ERC20 token on Remix as a trial.
I use three accounts for the token.

0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4: contract owner
0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2: approved account to send token from contract owner's account
0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db: receiver

When I run transferFrom function i get "ERC20InsufficientAllowance" error.
allowance function works normally, it shows allowance amount.
approve function works. After I approve token delegation, I can verify it.
function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public checkPaused returns (bool) {
    if (spender == address(0)) {
        revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
    }
    
    _approve(msg.sender, spender, value);

    return true;
}

function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
    _allowances[owner][spender] = value;

    emit Approve(owner, spender, value);
}    

getAllowance() function works too.
function getAllowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return _allowances[owner][spender];
}   

When I run transferFrom function, I'm getting ERC20InsufficientAllowance error. I could not understand why.
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public checkPaused returns (bool) {
    if (from == address(0) || to == address(0)) {
        revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
    }

    if (_balances[from] < value) {
        revert ERC20InsufficientBalance(msg.sender, _balances[from], value);
    }

    if (_allowances[from][to] < value) {
        revert ERC20InsufficientAllowance(to, _allowances[from][to], value); //error
    }

    _spendAllowance(from, to, value);

    _transfer(from, to, value);

    return true;
}

function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
    _balances[from] -= value;
    _balances[to] += value;

    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
}

function _spendAllowance(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
    _allowances[owner][spender] -= value;

    emit SpendAllowance(owner, spender, _allowances[owner][spender] - value);
}   

Here's the ERC20InsufficientAllowance error:
[vm]from: 0xAb8...35cb2to: ShivaToken.transferFrom(address,address,uint256) 0x80d...4BB9Bvalue: 0 weidata: 0x23b...003e8logs: 0hash: 0xd05...7a5d7
status  0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0xd0561c9e4f2195c3ab545a29e02f747ad54e28aae092ddd92a6923d49107a5d7
block hash  0x57c90613d4e65424402b0f96f97d671783bf024333cf48315f0b7b9e66082dda
block number    586
from    0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2
to  ShivaToken.transferFrom(address,address,uint256) 0x80d527dF27B22d91E1AC56868e7AA5e7Ebf4BB9B
gas 3000000 gas
transaction cost    30318 gas 
execution cost  8366 gas 
input   0x23b...003e8
output  0xfb8f41b20000000000000000000000004b20993bc481177ec7e8f571cecae8a9e22c02db000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8
decoded input   {
    "address from": "0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4",
    "address to": "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db",
    "uint256 value": "1000"
}
decoded output  {
    "0": "bool: true"
}
logs    []
raw logs    []
transact to ShivaToken.transferFrom errored: Error occurred: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Error provided by the contract:
ERC20InsufficientAllowance
Parameters:
{
 "spender": {
  "value": "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db",
  "documentation": "Address that may be allowed to operate on tokens without being their owner."
 },
 "allowance": {
  "value": "0",
  "documentation": "Amount of tokens a `spender` is allowed to operate with."
 },
 "needed": {
  "value": "1000",
  "documentation": "Minimum amount required to perform a transfer."
 }
}
If the transaction failed for not having enough gas, try increasing the gas limit gently.


Have you called the approve() function using 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4 (i.e., the contract owner) account, and passed the arguments as 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2 (spender) and 1000 (value)?

Yes, I have. I deploy contract, after that approve another wallet to use coins and i check allowance and i get coin amount  but transferFrom does not work.

It's working on my end though when I'm using Openzeppelin's ERC20. Can you make sure that the wallet address using which you've called the approve() function is same as the value of the from address parameter while calling the transferFrom() function?
